# How to set preference for downloading .dmg file using WebdriverIO?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I want to download a .dmg file using webdriverIO and when the link has been clicked the file download popup pops out which is a .dmg file. How can I handle the popup which asks "save" or "cancel"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is the save popup, then you can avoid the popup by setting the default download location for the browser.

**For CHROME:**

In the `wdio.conf.js` file, in `capabilities` add the following:

> Note: Before adding make sure you have defined `downloadDir` with the default path where the file needs to be saved.

```
capabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    // this overrides the default chrome download directory with our temporary one
    goog:chromeOptions: {
      prefs: {
        'download.default_directory': downloadDir
      }
    }
  }]
```

This code will set the default download directory and you will not see the pop up anymore.

More information: https://blog.kevinlamping.com/downloading-files-using-webdriverio/

Comment: Can you please tell about FIREFOX browser capabilities for setting the same?

Comment: Hi, i haven't personally tried it. But with some search in google i guess you need to add a npm module as first step. Follow [v5](https://webdriver.io/docs/firefox-profile-service.html) for WDIO V5 and [v4](http://v4.webdriver.io/guide/services/firefox-profile.html) for WDIO V4. Then as part of the `firefoxProfile` object, try adding the below: `"browser.download.folderList", 2`, `"browser.download.dir": "path"`, `"browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk": "add the mime type of your download file"`.

Comment: I followed the link http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/08/26/how-to-change-default-download-directory-for-firefox-browser-in-selenium-webdriver/ to get you the `firefoxProfile` options.

Comment: Instead of `chromeOptions` I am using now `goog:chromeOptions`. Probably they're renamed it.

Answer (score 1):

For folks landing here to find ways of downloading files using WebdriverIO in a headless browser, you can try the solution below. The solution above doesn't work for browsers running in the headless mode when working with the new [Devtools automation protocol](https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/09/16/devtools.html)

My setup is [headless Chromium + WebdriverIOv6 using Devtools protocol](https://github.com/vipulgupta2048/file-downloads-webdriverio-demo) to download a file by clicking the button using `click()` method. If you are using the same setup or any other browser with Devtools protocol then this below should work.

1. Install devtools-service `npm install @wdio/devtools-service --save-dev`

The package.json should have both `devtools` and `devtools-service` mentioned and installed.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.2.0",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^6.4.0",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.2.0",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^6.2.0",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.1.23",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.2.0",
    "devtools": "^6.2.0"
  },
```

2. Add `browser.cdp()` snippet in your specs file to send the `Page.setDownloadBehavior()` command to your browser in headless mode.
   The snippet needs to be added right before you are clicking the download button. Alter the `download_path` to what you need, make sure it's absolute.

```
browser.cdp('Page', 'setDownloadBehavior', {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath: download_path,
    });

// place before clicking the download button
$(.button).click()
```

3. In the wdio.conf.js file, your `capabilities` properties need to look something like this so that the download path works in GUI mode as well.

```
capabilities: [{
        browserName: "chrome",
        'goog:chromeOptions':{
          binary: "/usr/bin/chromium",
          args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox"],
        prefs: {
            'safebrowsing.enabled': false,
            'safebrowsing.disable_download_protection': true,
            "download": {
                "prompt_for_download": false,
                "directory_upgrade": true,
                "default_directory": download_path
            },
          }
        },
    }],
```

This should work. Read more, about [how it works](https://mixstersite.wordpress.com/2020/08/13/file-download-headless-chrome-chromium-webdriverio-devtools-chromedriver/) and several other solutions if this doesn't work.

Comment: Great answer! I've also noticed that when you are using cucumber with async you need to define separate step with just `browser.cdp(...)`. Clicking on download button MUST NOT be in this step (otherwise TypeError 'element.click' is not a function will be thrown). Step with defining download path may be the first step in scenario.

Comment: One more thing - you don't need to define `"default_directory": download_path`